# Open graph image size different when posting via API than when manually pasting in the same URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I post an open-graph URL in a Facebook post manually for our site, I get the larger image size showing up (The layout where the large image is on top and other OG meta-data is underneath the image).

[when posting manually http://item-photos.s3.amazonaws.com/OG-LargerPhoto.png](http://item-photos.s3.amazonaws.com/OG-LargerPhoto.png)

When I post the same exact open-graph URL via FB's API as a post to a group, I get the layout where the smaller image is on the left and the other meta data is on the right of it.

[when posting via API http://item-photos.s3.amazonaws.com/OG-SmallerPhoto.png](http://item-photos.s3.amazonaws.com/OG-SmallerPhoto.png)
I used the following restfb code to post the smaller photo:

```
def response = fbClient.publish("${groupId}/feed", 
            FacebookType,
            Parameter.with('message', "Some message to put in the message part of this post so it fills up the space a little bit...."),
            Parameter.with('link', 'https://dev.qpquo.com/apps/market/FB/de9b6e4b-ed4d-433f-bb4c-ef3afae2ef45/bid/50b29f03-2bec-4ab7-ac2d-fd1e385383e8'))
```

I've tried with and without a message in the code and even a just a photo and not matter what I get a smaller the image layout. What do I need to do to get the larger image layout when I post via the FB Rest API?

Comment: I posted this on the Facebook bug tracking system and they are calling it reproducible bug and have committed to looking into it.

https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/501306486654166/